# Estimator for AR(1) process

Tags: autocorrelation, autoregressive

Consider an AR(1) process
$X_{t+1}=cX_t+\epsilon_t,$
where $|c|<1$, and $\epsilon_t\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ are i.i.d,
and $X_0$ a fixed constant.

I am looking for a reference for the following fact:
the expression
$$\frac{\sum_{t=1}^T X_t X_{t-1}}{\sum_{t=1}^T X_{t-1}^2}$$
is a consistent estimator for $c$.
I note that this fact is proved in many books when $X_t$ is assumed to be 
a *stationary* AR(1) process, but I need this fact without the stationarity
assumption. It is `intuitively obvious' because any such sequence will
converge to stationarity as $t\rightarrow \infty$ - but where can I find the
rigorous argument?

Note that I assumed |c|<1, so clearly the process converges to
stationarity, but I assume a fixed initial condition $X_0$ - not a stationary sequence $X_t$ ($-\infty <t<\infty$) as is assumed in the derivations of the above estimator that I have seen.

Comment: @ChinG, no, the estimator remains consistent even in presence of a unit root, although it is no longer asymptotically normal.

Comment: Dana -- Please register and [merge](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) your accounts.